# Current division with a short

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9I3O0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This schematic is a bit difficult for me to understand due to the short (red). What is `I3`, the current over `R3` (indicated with open terminals, in blue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct but, in a comment, you write that you're unsure why. I've redrawn the schematic in a way that I hope will make it more clear why R4 is not in parallel with R1.

Can you take it from here?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB55DK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I am really grateful for your time. I now see R4 as not parallel with R1. I think ultimately, the source of my confusion is the meaning of that red wire: now I understand it has no meaning if it can be shrunken away. I think your schematic is helpful and together with the equations below, solve the problem clearly!

Answer (score 1):

Do current division twice: First get I4, the current through R4, then split that again for the remaining R2 and R3:

```
Step 1: I4 = (R1/(R1+R4+(R2||R3)))*I

Step 2: I3 = (R2/(R2+R3))*I4
```

Comment: Step 1 isn't correct. The resistance of the branch in parallel with R1 isn't just R4. Think about redrawing the schematic by 'shrinking' the red wire down to zero length.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I think you are saying that Step 1 should be: `(R1/(R1+R4+(R2||R3)))*I`, which I get after redrawing, as you suggested. Except that does not make any sense to me, since the red wire should be whisking away any current leaving the source and crossing R1. That is why I initially saw, and frankly still see, only R4 as parallel to R1, from the point of view of current leaving the source.

Comment: cccube, R4 cannot be in parallel with R1 since the bottom-most terminal of R4 is not connected (directly) to the bottom-most terminal of R1. Put another way, R1 is in parallel with the current source, but R4 is not.